# Replace ID part in relative path with a template string

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a requirement to inspect routes in .Net Core middleware and perform different actions based on different route. For this I have to do route comparisons for below sample routes returned from `HttpContext.Request.Path`:

```
/api/employees/2d50f670c72911ec861760be36a6c36a/authorise
/api/employees/9d50f670c72911ec861760be36a6c36a/decline
```

Because of dynamic ID present in the path, I have to split and join the string using below code:

```
route = "/api/employees";        
var pathSegments = request.Path.Value.Split('/');        
if (pathSegments.Length > 3 && Guid.TryParse(pathSegments[3], out Guid employeeId))
{
   route += @"/{employeeId}/"+string.Join("/", pathSegments.Skip(4));
}
```

While this works okay for URL comparison, I wanted to know if this can be done in a simpler way like `UriTemplate` class provides in WCF?

Comment: Maybe you can refer to the url redirect and url rewrite in the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the first two lines you wrote which you tried to partition the url, You can use the property [`Segments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.segments?view=netframework-4.8#system-uri-segments) of the `HttpContext.Url` object. It gives you a string array contains all segments.

BUT, I guess you're performing a wrong logic. Why don't you just do the desired action in an actual `Action`?

I mean the urls you mentioned to compare, surely call an `Action`(`Controller Method`), right? If so, why don't you just execute your desired actions in them?

For instance, if the `/api/employees/2d50f670c72911ec861760be36a6c36a/authorise` request must do a logic before the requested action (and this logic is done for every request), why should we do it in a `middleware`?

Because as far as I know, the `middlewares` are used for cross-cutting concerns.